# tcpdump/wireshark disconnect

Tags: network-programming, debian, wireshark, tcpdump

when i'm listening on wlan0 with tcpdump or even wireshark,
I'm always disconnected in 30s to 5 min.
Do you have any idea how to fix this?
I'm on a debian 64bits, i tryed wpa_spupplicant and network-manager.

Comment: Look at the last logs in the traffic log window of wireshark. This should give you a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after 5 month I found how to fix this issues.
I just have to update my network card drivers (in my case, iwlwifi)